# Console Web Service App Doesn't Work When Compiled, but works in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, web-services, reporting-services, visual-studio-2013, console

I am working on a console application that utilizes the Reporting Services execution webservice (ReportExeuction2005.asmx) on a SQL 2008 R2 SSRS server.  The intention is to have it run a report and save the report output to CSV file.  The report server is located remotely and accessed via HTTPS over the web.  I have the application written and when I run it via the debugger in Visual Studio 2013 it works as expected.  However, if I try to run the compiled .EXE in the BIN folder of the project, the web service call fails and throws the error "The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized".  I am passing in the same credentials both in the debugger and through the compiled .EXE, but they each result in different errors.

I also ran Fiddler when I was making the requests via both.  It appears that when I run the debugger it sends the request each request twice, the first time fails and then the second request succeeds.  Then when I do the same call via the compiled app it fails on the first attempt and throws the exception and exits.  In researching this, I found that the behavior in the debugger is the correct behavior as it is negotiating between Kerbose and NTLM authentication.  I am not sure why the debugger behavior is different from the compiled .EXE behavior though.  I tried to force the web service call to use NTLM authentication via a CredentialCache, but when I use a CredentialCache with the SSRS web service, it doesn't work at all.

Is there a way to force the compiled app to perform the same authentication as the debugger?

Here's the code I have so far:

```
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        //args = App.exe ReportName UserName Password Domain ExportedFileNameAndPath

        ReportExecutionService rse = new ReportExecutionService();

        rse.Url = "https://SomeWebServiceURL/ReportExecution2005.asmx";

        rse.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(args[1], args[2], args[3]);

        string historyID = null;
        string deviceInfo = null;
        string format = "CSV";
        Byte[] results;
        string encoding = String.Empty;
        string mimeType = String.Empty;
        string extension = String.Empty;
        ConsoleApplication2.webservice.Warning[] warnings = null;
        string[] streamIDs = null;


        string fileName = args[4];
        string _reportName = args[0];

        try
        {
            rse.ExecutionHeaderValue = new ExecutionHeader();

            ExecutionInfo ei = rse.LoadReport(_reportName, historyID);

            results = rse.Render(format, deviceInfo, out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);

            using (FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
            {
                stream.Write(results, 0, results.Length);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading args from the command line, make sure to put the values in double quotes if they contain spaces or special characters.

Comment: The quotes did the trick!  Apparently the debugger handles the arguments differently than the command shell and the command shell wanted to have it in quotes whereas the debugger recognized it correctly.  Thanks!